# function to change opacity after element.animate in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, jquery-animate

why is the opacity not returning to 0 in function resetImg() ?

it returns the position correctly when function is called.
I'm trying to do this without jquery at the moment...
i'm trying to get the animation part down before implementing into my full game.

Animation = https://codepen.io/hamisakim/pen/oNzyKeR

Full game = https://codepen.io/hamisakim/pen/ExgLrKV?editors=1011

HTML

```
<h1 id='Main Header'> Rock Paper Scissors </h1>
<h2> Choose below to test your luck </h2>
<div class='buttons'>
  <button id='rock'> ROCK </button>
  <button id='paper'>PAPER </button>
  <button id='scissors'> SCISSORS</button>
</div>
<h1 id='result'> </h1>

<div id='choiceImages'> 
<image id='playerImg' src='https://www.rock-paper-scissors-game.com/i/rock.png'>
  
  <image id='computerImg' src='https://www.rock-paper-scissors-game.com/i/scissors.png'>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body{text-align: center;}

.buttons {
  position:relative;
}

#computerImg{
max-width: 30%; 
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
position:relative;
 z-index: -1;
}


#playerImg { 
max-width: 30%; 
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0px 35px 0px 0px;
position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function playerWinAnimate() {
document.getElementById('playerImg').animate([
  //keyframes
  {transform : 'translateX(0px)'}, 
  {transform : 'translateX(250px)'}
],
 {
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: 1,   
  fill: 'forwards',
  
},)
document.getElementById('computerImg').animate([
  {opacity:1},
  {opacity:0}, ],
{duration:1000,
 delay: 1000,
iterations: 1,
fill: 'forwards'
}, )                                      
}
playerWinAnimate();

function resetImg(){
    document.getElementById('computerImg').style.opacity = 'initial';
  document.getElementById('playerImg').style.left = '-200px';

}

document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", resetImg);
document.getElementById("paper").addEventListener("click", resetImg);
document.getElementById("scissors").addEventListener("click", resetImg);
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery to animate?

Comment: By the way, you have several extra commas in your `animate` functions. If there is a closing bracket after your comma, then the comma is useless and it is best to remove it.

Comment: nope, not using any jquery just JS. Will tidy up with the commas!

Comment: function resetimg resets opacity to initial - what did you want it to do?

Comment: yeah it doesn't work for me though